# Is a multi-valued primary key itself a determinant when its member attributes are determinants of functional dependencies?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, functional-dependencies

This question is from homework. Please consider the following relation:

[image]

Is AB a determinant because A and B are determinants?

The following functional dependencies both determine CD:

A -> CD and B -> (CD)E

Is this a redundancy because A and B are both attributes of the primary key? In other words, since A and B are attributes of the primary key, are the following implicit functional dependencies:

AB -> CD and AB -> (CD)E

and therefore redundant?

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AB is a determinant** for the attributes `C`, `D` and `E`. This can indeed be deduced trivially from the functional dependencies of `A` and `B`.

You *could* call those functional dependencies **redundant** although the usual way to describe this problem is that some non-prime attributes (`C`, `D` and `E`) are partially dependent of the key `AB` (dependencies `A->CD` and `B->CDE`) and the table thus breaks the **second normal form**.

[Wikipedia - Second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)